# Inserting numerous incremental values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Got a table with 1200 rows. Added a new column which will contain incremental values -
Candidate1
Candidate2
Candidate3
.
.
.
Candidate1200

What is the best way to insert these values , non manual way. I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's an IDENTITY column (I called it `id` for this example):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
  SET new_column = (SELECT 'Candidate'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yt.id) AS VARCHAR(4))
                      FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
                     WHERE yt.id = YOUR_TABLE.id)
```

Comment: You got to it way faster than I did - I had to look up ROW_NUMBER in the docs!

Comment: Just wondering if there wasn't any ID column or we had to do the similar operation in a new table with 2 columns (ID, Candidate)

Comment: @Abey: ROW_NUMBER require an ORDER BY clause at a minimum, shouldn't matter if you're not caring about any given row getting a specific value.  I don't understand what you mean regarding "a new table with 2 columns (ID, Candidate)"

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use ROW_NUMBER

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Perhaps perform a query that gets the row number and use that query to perform an update on the source table where you concatenate the Row Number with 'Candidate'.